# MySQL OR statement not searching for second term

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM IC7400 WHERE de LIKE '%collector%' OR '%open%';
```

All it's returning is whatever the first term is, ignoring the term after the OR statement.

I verified this by switching the location of the terms and getting a different number of results. With collector first, I get 79 results, with open first I get 89 results.

Is there a reason because after looking through many forums, it doesn't seem like anyone else is really having this issue, and I can't find a good explanation on how to use only the OR statement properly.

I don't know what they did, but Google has really taken a hit on it's ability to return relevant search results. It used to be so good. Now it's getting to be as bad as those other ones that never return what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to repeat `de LIKE` after the `OR`:

```
SELECT * FROM IC7400 WHERE de LIKE '%collector%' OR de LIKE '%open%';
```

Comment: Oh . . . thank you so much. I'm actually taking an introductory class for this now, and the syntax is one of the greatest hurdles. Knowing exactly how it's supposed to be typed is kind of difficult.

Comment: Oh my goodness, how long does it take for us to choose a best answer? Why the waiting period? It worked, I want to mark it as best.

Comment: You're welcome! The reason you need to wait is that a better answer might come along, right after mine came. With many questions, like this one, it won't be the case. Though there are many valid questions with more than one valid answer. This way you need to wait in order to choose which answer is really the best.

Comment: Also, since your still learning the syntax. Keep in mind to use `( )` on the right places when combining `OR`s and `AND`s.